# How configure apache to load index.html and index.php?

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess, server-configuration

here is my doubt, I have the following structure:

root/index.html
root/api/index.php

I have coded with the php built in server, so when I run php -S localhost:3000 everything runs smooth but when I updload it to my vps or run it with apache in my localmachine my backend is not initialized and even the postman can acccess my endpoints.

I know maybe a configuration on htaccess can solve it, but I have no idea how to do it, the whole scenario:

I access my root (http://localhost:3000) that loads my index.html
on javascript it sends requests to http://localhost:3000/api/uri
when my server is running on php built in server it fetch all the data on back end that returns to my front end all perfectly

thanks for your help

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added .htaccess from lavarel e all worked, looks like it had a problem reading the route system I created.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).